# JSDoc for parameter property declarations doesn't apply to the properties

Tags: visual-studio, comments, typescript, jsdoc

If I make a constructor with a parameter property declaration like this:

```
constructor(public someProperty) { }
```

I would like to be able to apply JSDoc to `someProperty`:

```
/** @param someProperty Example property documentation */
```

And have this documentation apply to both the parameter and the corresponding property.

However, in Visual Studio, the documentation only seems to apply to the parameter. I don't know if this is a flaw in the Visual Studio integration or the language specification. Which is it? Or is it neither?

How can I achieve this without explicitly declaring the property?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this.

```
class Foo
{
    /** @param someProperty Example property documentation */
    constructor(
        /**
        * The documentation needs to go here
        */
        public someProperty
    )
    {
    }
}


new Foo("").someProperty;
```

It is understandable that it could be the same documentation for `@param` and the property, but not necessarily.

In the `@param` you will only have text, while in the other block of documentation you can create a much more complex explanation of the property.

However, if you think it could be a feature you can [suggest it here](https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/topics/5488/language-specification).

If the property documentation is not present but the `@param` is, it could attach the documentation. Otherwise, if the property documentation is present, then it would override the `@param`. That would be nice.